# Follow up on cinquefoil knot

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Using the following Seifert surface of the cinquefoil knot

[image]

I get the following Seifert matrix (of linking numbers):
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix}- 1 &1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &-1 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0 &-1& 1\\ 0 &0 &0& -1\end{pmatrix}$$

I compute the matrix of the corresponding bilinear form
$$ I = S^T - S = 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 &  0 &  0 \\
   1  & 0 & -1  & 0 \\
   0 &  1 &  0 & -1 \\
   0  & 0  & 1 &  0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and a corresponding symplectic basis
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$f_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1 \\1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$f_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$$

And I get $\mathrm{Arf}(K) = e_1^T S e_1 f_1^T S f_1 + e_2^T S e_2 f_2^T S f_2 = 2 \equiv_2 0 \neq 1$

Where is my mistake? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's knot a symplectic basis :,(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the matrices $I$ and $S$ the following is a symplectic basis

$$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ f_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$f_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

yielding

$$ \mathrm{Arf}(K) = e_1^T S e_1 f_1^T S f_1 + e_2^T S e_2 f_2^T S f_2 = 9 \equiv_2 1$$
as it should.